# Can load-on-startup in web.xml be used to load an arbitrary class on startup?

Tags: servlets, initialization, web.xml

How can I load an arbitrary class on startup in Tomcat?
I saw `load-on-startup` tag for `web.xml` file, but can I use it and how should I implement my class?

```
<servlet-name>??</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>??</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>10</load-on-startup>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Those are meant to specify the loading order for servlets. However, servlets are more meant to control, preprocess and/or postprocess HTTP requests/responses while you sound like to be more looking for a hook on webapp's startup. In that case, you rather want a `ServletContextListener`.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do your thing during webapp's startup.
    }
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do your thing during webapp's shutdown.
    }
}
```

If you're not on Servlet 3.0 yet (and thus can't use `@WebListener`), then you need to manually register it in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

#### See also:

- [Servletcontainer lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909)

Comment: If I want to startup my application with an specific servlet (which is not possible to be a static page) is this here the only way? I would use your ContextListener with an forward?

Answer (score 8):

The element **load-on-startup indicates that this servlet should be loaded (instantiated and have its init() called) on the startup of the Web application**. The element content of this element must be an integer indicating the order in which the servlet should be loaded.In other words, container loads the servlets in ascending integer value. **The 0 value will be loaded first then 1, 2, 3 and so on.**

Let's try to understand it by the example given below:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>  
 ....  
  //=====================servlet 1==============
  <servlet>  
   <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>  
   <servlet-class>com.javatpoint.FirstServlet</servlet-class>  
   <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>  //value given 0(zero)
  </servlet>  

  //=====================servlet 2==============
  <servlet>  
   <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>  
   <servlet-class>com.javatpoint.SecondServlet</servlet-class>  
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>   //value given 1(one)  
  </servlet>  

 ...  
</web-app>
```

There are defined 2 servlets, both servlets will be loaded at the time of project deployment or server start. But, servlet1 will be loaded first then servlet2.

**Passing negative value :**  If you pass the negative value, servlet will be loaded at request time, at first request.

Answer (score 3):

enfix,

Your XML looks good.

You should place a init() method in your servlet class, that gets called when your server bootsup. doGet, doPost and do methods get called only when there is an incoming request.

```
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void init()
    {
        //initialize( or add a log statement to debug)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer here - because with the load-on-startup integer you can control that eg. your servlet is being started after all other load-on-startup servlets. If you don't care, then a ServletContextListener should be uses, which is run before all these startup servlets.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for Tomcat 7.0
Step 1:
  Create war file  for your webapp/servlets.
  If you are using Eclipse, File->Export->Web->WAR file, and save it to a known location.

Step 2:
  Find out the home folder for your tomcat.
  For that, go to tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/bin and execute ./startup.sh
  This will print out couple of global variable names.
  Note down the one for CATALINA_HOME.

Step 3:
  Copy the war file from Step 1 in CATALINA_HOME/webapps

Step 4:
  Next, Create an xml file in CATALINA_HOME/conf/{Engine}/localhost/MyServlets.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Context deployOnStartup="true" docBase="/home/ubuntu/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/" reloadable="true">
<Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```

Change docBase to point to location where you copied the war file in Step 3.

Now, you can go go to tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/bin and execute ./startup.sh.
Your servlets will be automatically started.
Hope this helps.